# ShareLatex knitr install package

Tags: r, knitr, sharelatex

Sharelatex comes with a few R library's that you can query. However, it is impossible for me to install a package or query a non pre-installed package. The package I am trying to use is the arm package:

```
library(arm)
## Error in library(arm):  there is no package called 'arm'
```

Someone seems to have asked the same [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28034656/r-knitr-sharelatex-install-packagesxyz) but the question given doesn't work.